# How do I read cells of another program's TStringGrid control?

Tags: vb.net, delphi

How can I extract items from other application's gridview? The class name of the control is `TStringGrid`.

I can get the handle of the `TStringGrid` window with `FindWindowEx` using these declarations:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function FindWindow( _
 ByVal lpClassName As String, _
 ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, _
                  ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, _
                  ByVal lclassName As String, _
                  ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
End Function
```

code:

```
    Dim TheMainForm As Integer = FindWindow("form", "fname")
    Dim GV As Integer = FindWindowEx(TheMainForm, 0, "TStringGrid", "")
```

How can I extract the items from GV (TStringGrid handle)?

(I have to finish this project by tomorrow.)

Comment: Interesting topic, but like Hans says, this will not be done by tomorrow. Plus I'm sure it would take someone who knows both VB and Delphi, which I gave up VB long ago back when I was first introduced to Delphi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Delphi string grid is not a windows control. It's a custom Delphi control. As such it doesn't respond to windows messages asking for its content. Without the source of the app you would need to reverse engineer the app to work out where the content is stored.

Realistically the most effective way to do this will be to inject a thread into the target application. That thread can then do the work of reading the information and can then use some IPC to get the data back to your VB process.

In order to do this you will, ideally, need:

1. Knowledge of the exact version of Delphi used to build the app.
2. A deep understanding of the Delphi compiler and RTL.
3. The Delphi VCL source code for `TStringGrid`.

I've no idea how you'll be able to synchronize your reading thread with the Delphi app.

Anyway, whilst what you ask for is, in theory possible, in reality it is completely impractical. The sensible solution is to ask the authors of the Delphi program to provide an automation interface.

Comment: ok, thank you. what about process memory? maybe i can read the information from process memory?

Comment: Sure you can read another processes memory. But which bit of memory contains the information you need? Injecting just makes reading the memory somewhat simpler. It doesn't actually matter which way you do it, you still need to know what to read.

Comment: you are right, there is no order in the memory. if you find another way to get cells information Inform me.

Comment: Maybe you will be able to use RTTI after injecting, but you will have to deal with memory manager sharing.

Comment: ok, thanks. i will try it. maybe you can contact with me by skype(this is more convenient)

Comment: Sorry, no Skype, no e-mail. Just here.